# Unorthodox linked list in python

Tags: python, linked-list

As part of my A-Level cirriculum ive got to witre a program to create a linked list with the ability to add and delete nodes.

Unfortunatley my exam board has dictated that this must done in a specific unorthodox way. They want the nodes to be objects with two atributes (data and Pointer) stored in a standard list.

It is incrediably important that it done in this way as the exam board doesnt accept any other methods :(

This is the contructor method for the node that i must use

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self) :
        self.data = int()
        self.pointer = -1
```

I've spent ages trying all sorts of things to get this to work properly but i cant seem to get it to keep the pointers correct.

Could somebody help me with a working soloution, any help is hugley appreciated.

EDIT:
As suggested im posting my best current attempt.

So far ive got the initilisation and adding down (i think) but i need help with deleting. I also think i may need to adpat my adding code for deleting to work. Although ive got absoutley no idea how to go about keeping the pointers pointing to the correct nodes after being deleted.

Initialisation:

```
def initialiselist():
    List = [Node() for i in range(10)]
    startpointer = nullpointer
    freelistptr = 0

    for index in range(9):
        List[index].pointer = index + 1
    List[9].pointer = nullpointer

    for i in List:
        print(i.data, i.pointer)
    return List, startpointer, freelistptr
```

Adding nodes:

```
def insertnode(List, startpointer, freelistptr, newdata):
    if startpointer == -1:                      #If list is empty
        List[freelistptr].data = newdata
        startpointer = freelistptr
        freelistptr = List[startpointer].pointer
        List[startpointer].pointer = -1
        return(List,startpointer,freelistptr)

    for i in List:
        if i.data == newdata:        
            print("You cannot have duplicate data")
            return(List,startpointer,freelistptr)

    if freelistptr == -1:
        print("The list is full")
        return(List,startpointer,freelistptr)

    elif freelistptr != -1:         #If Lis is not empty
        List[freelistptr].data = newdata

        if List[startpointer].data > newdata:             #If the new data is less than the startpointer 
            temp = List[freelistptr].pointer
            List[freelistptr].pointer = startpointer                    
            startpointer = freelistptr                                  
            freelistptr = temp
            return(List,startpointer,freelistptr)

        else:                                               #If the new data is greater than the startpointer

            if List[startpointer].pointer == -1:                            
                List[startpointer].pointer = freelistptr                
                temp = freelistptr                                      
                freelistptr = List[freelistptr].pointer             
                List[temp].pointer = -1
                return(List,startpointer,freelistptr)

            nextnodeptr = List[startpointer].pointer                        
            previousnodeptr = startpointer
            newnodeptr = freelistptr
            temp2 = List[freelistptr].pointer

            while True:
                if List[nextnodeptr].pointer == -1:
                    if List[nextnodeptr].data > newdata:
                        List[newnodeptr].pointer = nextnodeptr
                        List[previousnodeptr].pointer = newnodeptr
                        break
                    elif List[nextnodeptr].data < newdata:
                        List[nextnodeptr].pointer = newnodeptr
                        temp2 = List[freelistptr].pointer
                        List[newnodeptr].pointer = -1
                        break
                if List[nextnodeptr].data > newdata:
                    temp2 = List[freelistptr].pointer
                    List[newnodeptr].pointer = nextnodeptr
                    List[previousnodeptr].pointer = newnodeptr
                    break   
                else:
                    previousnodeptr = nextnodeptr
                    nextnodeptr = List[nextnodeptr].pointer

            freelistptr = temp2   
            return (List,startpointer,freelistptr)
```

I know this is just a complete wall of text but im not used to posting here so im sorry.

My question is how do i delete nodes?

Comment: That seems like a fairly typical way to do a linked list. `data` is the info stored in the node and `pointer` is the next node in the list.

Comment: Also, if you want help, you will need to post the code you have.

Comment: You could help yourself by posting the most promising of your attempts & explain what problem(s) you have with it.

Comment: if they are stored in a list, how do you know which is first? Is it always the first item in the list? Should you maintain the list so that it duplicates the linked-list structure?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I dont think ive got a list object. Im pretty sure ive got objects in a list. i think you missunderstand what theryre asking. they want a standard list, with objects inside them. the linked list is not an object in this senario.

Comment: I would implement the linked list as a class, for encapsulation, and met the specifications internally to that class.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I cannot implement the linked list as a class as it is not the accpeted way from my exam board, there is no workaround for this and it is non-negotiable.

Comment: freelistptr seems to be the next empty position. However, you assume it is assignable (which is wrong). If there is an item there, then either it's already a node, or you constructed an invalid object as a placeholder (which is itself bad), or it's an IndexError, or (best case I guess) there is a value of None in the list at that index, so you have to construct a node to go there.

Comment: This indicates that you do not have a good list of your design invariants. These are the things that are always true about the data structure. If you delete a node, and fix it so all the invariants are maintained, then the delete is good.

Comment: Ok. Re-reading the question I see the nodes must be _stored in a standard list._ Not sure I understand what `pointer` is supposed to point to, though. Are the items randomly located in the list and the pointers are used to order them without moving them in the list?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yes the items are are ramndomly located in the list. pointer points to the index of the node with the next highest value for data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the 'unorthodox' requirement correctly, the underlying structure of the nodes should be a standard list.  This would mean that your node class should be a subclass of `list` without any attributes of its own.

Here's how I would approach this:

```
class ListNode(list):

    @property
    def pointer(self): return (self[1:] or [None])[0]
    @pointer.setter
    def pointer(self,node): self[:] = [self.data,node]

    @property
    def data(self): return self[0] if self else None
    @data.setter
    def data(self,value): self[:1] = [value]

    def addNode(self,node): # to end of chain
        if self.pointer: self.pointer.addNode(node)
        else:            self.pointer = node

    def append(self,value):
        self.addNode(ListNode([value]))

    def insertNode(self,node): # before this node
        if self.pointer: node.addNode(self.pointer)        
        self.data,node.data       = node.data,self.data
        self.pointer,node.pointer = node,self.pointer

    def find(self,value):
        if self.data == value: return self
        if self.pointer: return self.pointer.find(value)

    def deleteNode(self,node): # needs to start from a previous node
        if self.pointer is node: self.pointer = node.pointer
        else:                    self.pointer.deleteNode(node)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.data}" + (f" --> {self.pointer}" if self.pointer else "")
```

*Note that once the data and pointer properties are defined with a setter and getter, the rest of the methods don't need to know what the underlying storage structure actually is*

usage:

```
head  = ListNode([0])
head.append(1)
head.append(2)
head.append(3)

print(head)
# 0 --> 1 --> 2 --> 3

node2 = head.find(2)
node4 = ListNode([4])
node2.insertNode(node4)

print(head)
# 0 --> 1 --> 4 --> 2 --> 3

node2 = head.find(2)
head.deleteNode(node2)

print(head)
# 0 --> 1 --> 4 --> 3
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response altough this method is too advanced for me and more importantley the examiner, who will be marking it during the exam (dont worry youre not giving me my coursework, its based on a pre-release matirial). I need the solotion to be strictley a continuation of the code ive provided.

Comment: In any case, it seems I misunderstood the requirement because the statement *the nodes to be objects with two atributes (data and Pointer) stored in a standard list* could mean either the objects are stored in a list or the attributes are stored in a list.  I chose the later but it would seem they want you to use and manage the list as if it were raw memory.

Comment: Nah dont worry about it, im sorry my explanation was not the best